# webGLRenderer slow down performance with mathquill equation editing

Tags: three.js

I'm having a problem I can't seem to figure out how to fix. I'm using both mathquill (https://github.com/laughinghan/mathquill#readme) and Three.js (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) for a project.

However, when I append a webGLRenderer to my page DOM, it slows down performance (or do something funky) with the equation editor of mathquill. Basically, the cursor becomes impossible to see, and it becomes really hard to type anything. If you comment out the line below (####), you will be able to compare what I mean when interacting with the equation in the textbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mathquill.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewport" z-index:"-1">
<canvas width="1920" height="713">
  </div>
  <div class="math" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);position:absolute;z-index:2;width:1920px;height:713px;top:150px;left:150px;">
    <p><span class="mathquill-editable">\frac{5+\theta}{\int_0^x\theta}</span></p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mathquill.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="three.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      var latexMath = $('.mathquill-editable').bind('keydown keypress').keydown().focus();
    });

    window.onload = function() {

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( 800, 600 );
        // ###########  uncomment the next line ######################
        //document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    };
  </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: it turn out that the code above works fine with firefox (version 11.0) but not with chrome (Version 20.0.1132.57).